# Prove $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm struggling with this one. Any hints? $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$.

Comment: For every $g\in G$, define $u_g \in Aut(G)$ by $$u_g(a) := gag^{-1}$$ The map $g \mapsto u_g$ gives a homomorphism to which you can apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** For each $g \in G$ define $f_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

Then $g \to f_g$ is a group morphism from $G$ to $Aut(G)$. What is the Kernel of this map?

Comment: Note if $g$ is in the kernel, $f_g = \text{id}_G$, that is: $gxg^{-1} = x$, for all $x \in G$. This says something about $g$.